# How to rotate X-axis labels in bokeh figure?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, bokeh

I'm just starting to use Bokeh. Below I create some args I use for the [rect figure](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.rect).

```
x_length = var_results.index * 5.5
```

Multiplying the index by 5.5 gave me more room between labels.

```
names = var_results.Feature.tolist()
y_length = var_results.Variance
y_center = var_results.Variance/2
```

`var_results` is a Pandas dataframe that has a typical, sequential, non-repeating index. `var_results` also has a column `Features` that is strings of non-repeated, names, and finally it has a column `Variance` which is dtype float.

```
r = figure(x_range = names, 
           y_range = (-0.05,.3), 
           active_scroll = 'wheel_zoom', 
           x_axis_label = 'Features', 
           y_axis_label = 'Variance')



r.rect(x_length, 
       y_center, 
       width=1, 
       height=y_length, 
       color = "#ff1200")
output_notebook()
show(r)
```

I'm essentially making a bar chart with rectangles. Bokeh seems to be very customizable. But my graph looks rough around the edges, literally.

[image]

As you can see there is an ugly smudge just below the chart and above the x-axis title 'Features'. This is the label titles (technically the rectangle titles). How do I create space for and perhaps rotate to 45 degrees the labels so that they are readable and not just an overlapping mess?

Comment: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-orientation

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In order to rotate the labels e.g. by 90 degrees to the left, you can set `major_label_orientation` to π/2. This can be done either when creating the axis element (as a kwarg to the axis constructor if you are using low level plotting) or also after you have created a plot/figure, for instance by:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/2

# or alternatively:
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
```

See also [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-orientation) in the documentation.

Comment: Strangely this seems not to be working for me--does it work with text labels?  One would think it would take all labels to be text, but that's all I can see which differentiates my situation.  The plot renders if I don't add this line.

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative to rotation, you [set the orientation to a fixed value](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-orientation):

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
```

should do what you want, too.