# How to rotate X-axis labels in bokeh figure in Cuxfilter?

Tags: python, bokeh, rapids

I have the exact same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354648/how-to-rotate-x-axis-labels-in-bokeh-figure), except the implementation within [`cuxfilter`](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuxfilter/stable/charts/bokeh_charts.html) (RAPIDS)

[image]

```py
cux_df = cuxfilter.DataFrame.from_dataframe(test)
chart0 = cuxfilter.charts.bar('index', 'count')
chart0.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
chart0.view()
```

yields:

```py
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'xaxis'
```

Comment: Oh which type is `chart0`?

Comment: can you see chart0 is a bar chart in the line above?

Comment: I am asking for `type(chart0)`.

Comment: @mosc9575 :   `cuxfilter.charts.bokeh.plots.Bar`

Comment: @mosc9575 here's a direct link to the source: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuxfilter/blob/branch-0.19/python/cuxfilter/charts/bokeh/bokeh.py

Comment: Try try `chart0.chart.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"`.This should solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mosc9575 rightly mentioned in the comments, doing the following should resolve your issue:

```py
chart0.chart.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
```

The underlying `chart0.chart` is a bokeh object, and its possible to apply all the bokeh properties to it directly.