# bokeh x-axis xticks rotation?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

[image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kmpv.png)  [updated plot image(still looks off)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6NX.png)

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(dt=df['Date/Time'],
                                       temp=df['Temp (C)'],
                                       dew=df['Dew Point Temp (C)']))
    
p=figure(x_range=df['Date/Time'],
        title='Temperature across the year',
        x_axis_label='Date and Time',
        y_axis_label='Temperature in C',
        sizing_mode='stretch_width',
        plot_height=300)
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"


p.line(x='dt',
      y='temp',
      source=source,
      legend_label='Temp C')

p.line(x='dt',
      y='dew',
      source=source,
      legend_label='Dew Point Temp C',
      color='red')

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Temperature','@temp'),('Dew Temp','@dew'),('date','@dt')]))

show(p)
```

working on bokeh in pandas, but all the dates on the x axis are overlapping. how can i adjust my code to rotate the dates vertically on the xaxis?

Comment: you should provide a fully reproducible example, including data (and the image you obtain)

Comment: please find attached an image of my plot

Comment: i can see there has been a visual change but it hasnt solved the problem, new image and updated code attached above

Comment: You need to convert the values in the `dt` column to actual datetime values and not pass xrange. You are currently using string values making a categorical axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an axis element on your x axis first.
Afterwards, you can use the `major_label_orientation` method to perform a rotation of π/2. An example below:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/2

# or alternatively:
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
```

I know this thanks to this thread : [How to rotate X-axis labels in bokeh figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354648/how-to-rotate-x-axis-labels-in-bokeh-figure)